# Manipulating objects , constructors?

Tags: java, arrays, object, constructor

Hello english is not my main language
i'm not sure how to explain my problem or should the title be titlted

so...please jump to House class !
Thank you in advance

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Furniture f1 = new Furniture("chair", 2);
        Furniture f2 = new Furniture("bed", 20);
        Furniture f3 = new Furniture("workbench", 7);
        Furniture f4 = new Furniture("drawer", 15);

        Furniture [] foo = {f1,f2,f3}; 

        // public House(Furniture[] fur)
        House h1 = new House(foo);

        //  public House(Furniture f, House p) 
        House h2 = new House(f4, h1);

    }

}
```

**Furniture class**

```
public class Furniture {

    String name;
    int weight;

    public Furniture(String name, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public static void display(Furniture f) {
    System.out.println("This furniture is a " + f.name + " and weights " + f.weight);
    }

}
```

**House class**

```
// My House class contains one attribut which is an array of Furniture
public class House {

    Furniture[] fur;

    // Should build an empty house
    public House() {

    }

    // Should define the house with the array content
    public House(Furniture[] fur) {
        this.fur = fur;
    }

    // Should build an house containing the Furniture f and the furniture of the House p
    public House(Furniture f, House p) {

    // I'm so confused here, I'm not sure how to start 



    }

}
```

I've thought about making a new array which length is the array contained in the house and add +1 ( for the furniture f ) then do a loop to get all the furnitures of the house p and add them to the new array with the new furniture f

I tried to do p.length ( p for the house ) but it doesn't work. I kind of understand why but on the other I don't, how can I access to the array of the house ? Is this the wrong approach, I can't find another way

Comment: `p` is not array so you can't write `p.length`, `p` *holds* `fur` array. You can access it via `p.fur` and then access its `length` via `p.fur.length`.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you.
I'll try

Comment: Follow @Pshemo idea access furniture of arrays using p.fur and access length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access array like that because your House isn't array, you must say `houseInstance.fur` in other to get access to array, where houseInstance is an instance of House class.

Considering on how to make new house with furniture from old and another new piece of furniture:

This is how you can do it using your approach:

```
    public House(Furniture f, House p) {

        // I'm so confused here, I'm not sure how to start 
        this.fur = new Furniture[p.fur.length+1];

        this.fur[0] = f; // Add new furniture

        // Make new instances of furniture from another house(They don't share reference but have same values)
        // Suggested way of doing it
        for(int i =0; i < p.fur.length;i++){
            this.fur[i+1] = new Furniture(p.fur[i].name, p.fur[i].weight);
        }
        /*
           This will share furniture reference between those 2 houses
            so changing one will change another
            This should be avoided
        for(int i =0; i < p.fur.length;i++){
            this.fur[i+1] = p.fur[i];
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: Don't post only the solution, post where the error is, why does he get that error...

Comment: @AlexCuadrón I was in process of writing solution, that was just missclick after copying code from editor...

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to find a similar solution thanks to Alex Cuadron and Pschemo but I didn't think about this.fur instead I created a new array

Comment: @FilipRistic I've just checked out now. It's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `p` is not an array (it's a class (House class)), so you can't call for the length of fur directly with `p.length`.  Instead use `p.fur.length;` where you want to obtain the length of `fur` array. Because this way you're referring first to the class: `p.fur` and then accessing the array inside that class (`fur`).